# What flavor of regex should be used with DBpedia/Virtuoso SPARQL?

Tags: regex, sparql, rdf

I'm trying to match only full strings, and not substrings in sparql using FILTER.

I am querying on [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) (which is hosted on [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)).

I'm not quite sure if SPARQL supports wordbounds, seeing how using something like

```
FILTER(regex(?name, "V", "i"))
```

will find those who contain V, IV, VI, VII, and so forth.

Now, I've tried using

```
FILTER(regex(?name, "\<V\>", "i"))
```

which generates a compile error on the endpoint

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad escape sequence in a short double-quoted string at '"\'
```

I've also tried doing

```
FILTER(regex(?name, "\bV\b", "i"))
```

And while this query is accepted, it doesn't return any results, which I guess is because it takes it as backspace instead of wordbounds.

I've tried looking for the flavor it uses, the only thing I found is that it uses [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This error message [comes from the lexer](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/27a00badbcf7f3ad37f62cb2003878fe07fa6ead/libsrc/Wi/sparql_l.l#L460), not from the regex engine. So try to double escape that: `\\bV\\b` and see what happens. Other than that, the flavor [appears to be PCRE](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/27a00badbcf7f3ad37f62cb2003878fe07fa6ead/libsrc/util/pcrelib) (at least this lib is referenced).

Comment: Thank you, I just tried double escaping that, no more error, but just as \b, doesn't return any results. I'll take a look into PCRE, thanks!

Comment: PCRE is about the best thing you could get, and it supports `\b` for sure, but maybe the `regex` function anchors the pattern ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, so try `.*?\bV\b.*`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Just tried it, still no results. Maybe the DBPedia sparql uses another flavor or an older standard? It seems really weird not being able to match neither with \b nor \</>

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Found it, I can use \\s in order to delimit it to spaces (i.e. V has to have a space on the left and one on the right) so \\sV\\s works fine. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hmm that's not quite the same thing as `\b`, but if it works for you then I guess it's good enough.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski After reading your comment, I realize you're right, it wouldn't take into account if the word was the first or the last. Changed it to (^|\\s)V(\\s|$) and now it seems to work so far

Comment: It also doesn't take into account other word delimiting characters, think of: `"V" 'V' V,` etc

Comment: That's also true. However, I am querying for names, basically. And the descriptions of those names, so it's very rare they would appear between single or double quotes, I just added (\\s|$|,|\.) at the end to catch the comma and the period. Thanks!

Comment: Ask the Virtuoso developers if something is unclear with the supported REGEX flavor - DBpedia is deployed on the Virtuoso triple store.

Comment: Formally, the regex language is that from XQuery/XPath Functions and Operators : https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax  In practice, java regex, perl and other programming languages regexs are very close.

Comment: @AndyS I agree, however, in some cases there are subtle differences such as word boundary with \b, or \y or \< and \>, which I could not find specified. none of those seems to work with Virtuoso, so I just settled for a longer and more specific expression

Comment: This seems rather a good question for the [Virtuoso Users](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) and/or [DBpedia Discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/) mailing lists...

Comment: @Manu Andrei is it possible to see your full query to make some test ?

Comment: @ManuAndrei For me it works with word boundaries, see `select distinct ?s ?l where {
?s a dbo:SoccerClub .
?s rdfs:label ?l
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l),'en'))
FILTER(regex(str(?l), "\\bD", "i"))
} LIMIT 100` which returns soccer clubs with a word beginning with d in its name.

Comment: @FrancoRondini I'm sorry, I can't share that at this point in time, I'm under an NDA until it gets released...

Comment: @AKSW For some reason it seems to have no effect for me if I add \\bString\\b

Comment: Hm, I don't know your query, but my example also works for whole strings, e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?l WHERE {
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerClub> ;
     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l),'en'))
  FILTER(REGEX(STR(?l), "\\bDundee\\b", "i"))
} LIMIT 100` Without having more information about the query, it's impossible help you - sorry.

Comment: It's not PCRE, it's XML Schema Datatype regular expressions. I'm adding answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word bounds work with `\\b`, see

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?l WHERE {
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerClub> ;
     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l),'en'))
  FILTER(REGEX(STR(?l), "\\bD", "i"))
} LIMIT 100
```

which returns soccer clubs with a word beginning with "d" in its English name.

*ETA: Virtuoso developers report that it uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions).*

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  As I read the spec, the regex syntax is that from XML Datatypes, and I can't seem to find `\b` in there.  I think `\W` is the "non-word character" which would essentially be a word boundary, I think.  That or one of the Z codes (separators)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor This is just what I tried on DBpedia resp. Virtuoso and it seems to accept `\b` as word boundary. I'm not a developer of Virtuoso and I don't know what kind of REGEX engine they use. In the documentation I couldn't find anything relevant. I'm not sure about the differences between `\b` and `\W`, but this query returns different results then: `SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?l WHERE {
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerClub> ;
     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l),'en'))
  FILTER(REGEX(STR(?l), "\\bDundee", "i"))
} LIMIT 100`

Comment: With `\b` labels beginning with "Dundee" are returned as well (e.g. `"Dundee F.C."@en`), with `\W` it returns only the one after a `(`, i.e. it seems like at least one character is needed then: `"Strathmore F.C. (Dundee)"@en`

Comment: I asked the Virtuoso developers now, to get clarification regarding the implement REGEX flavor. I'll let you know once I got an answer.

Comment: Oh, I wasnt worried about whether it works in virtuoso, but I just can't figure out where in the specs it says that '\' should work.  That could be a shortcoming on my part, or it could be another place where virtuoso's implementation deviates from the standard.  I'm just trying to figure out which.

Comment: I got an answer: It is the variant described in the Wikipedia doc at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: According to the XPath function that you refer to, I can see this line "It is recommended that implementers consult [Unicode Regular Expressions] for information on using regular expression processing on Unicode characters." Which maps to http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/ . Here, simple word boundaries are defined by `\b`, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Simple_Word_Boundaries

Comment: perfect, that's what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

SPARQL 1.1's **regex** function is described in [17.4.3.14 REGEX](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-regex) of the standard:

> Invokes the XPath [fn:matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function to match text against a regular expression pattern. The regular expression language is defined in XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators section [7.6.1 Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax).

Following some links, you'll end up at the XML Schema definition for regular expressions, at [Appexndix F: Regular Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs).  If you look for Multi-Character Escape in that document, you'll find:

> - \w
>     [#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}] (all characters except the set
>     of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters)
> - \W
>     [^\w]

As I read that, I think that **\W** is the word separator that you're looking for.